# What problems can arise from storing a DbContext reference in a POCO object?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, c#-4.0, design-patterns

I am new to a 15 year old application. The team lead has started using Entity Framework + alongside existing WebForms + Sprocs.

Some POCOs (domain entities) in EF have properties containing references to the DbContext, usually parent objects at the top of an object graph. As I attempt to write tests, I continually get Context Disposed exceptions.

```
    public EmployerService(int UserID, Entities entities) // business layer
    {
        this.UserID = UserID;
        _entities = entities;
    }        


    internal Employer CreateEmployer()
    {
        Employer  employer = _entities.Employers.Create();
        employer.MasterItem = _entities.MasterItems.Create();
        employer.MasterItem.LastModified = _entities.ItemLastModifieds.Create();
        employer.DBContext = _entities;
        ...
        return employer;
    }
```

More to the point, the project references are not clean. The POCOs reference Data and Business logic layers. I am building a case to get the DbContext references out of the POCO objects, but my search is just beginning.

So my question is, what design principles support or reject referencing the DAL layer from the POCOs?

Comment: This does not look _really_ bad yet. It looks like it's more a context life cycle problem (the context exists too long). Are there references to the context in the domain entities as well? (like in `Employer` itself). _That_ would be bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAL layer sneaks into Business Logic layer. Service now tightly coupled to Entity Framework (BTW I don't think it's good idea to add reference to EntityFramework.dll into your domain project). Consider we are moving to NHibernate. What you should change? Everybody would think it's a DAL task. But wait guys, I have some DAL in my domain! We should change EmployerService class.

So, keep your domain entities persistent ignorant. Especially keep them ignorant of concrete persistence technology you are using. And I think better place for Employer creation is a factory. Also I don't understand why you are not using simple constructors here? Looks like you can avoid Entity Framework usage during Employer creation.

Comment: It's existing code. I'm new to the group and working to convince them to change, but constraints on the team lead's time make him not want to take risks.

Comment: @JCii looks like your team do not use unit tests and all is working now. What you ask from their purpose is simple refactoring, which will not give some valuable (currently) benefits, but will require regression testing of whole application. Refactoring is always hard to ask for on legacy projects

Answer (score 0):

The most `vocal` `design principle` here is **that you're having problems** with the current design.

`DbContext` is supposed to be used as a `short-living` - and it's not meant to be stored `for later`. The reference you're holding doesn't mean much, as it gets `Disposed`.

To the very least you should check if it's `Disposed` (you can do that by overriding `Dispose` I guess, setting a flag or something). **But what to do if it is?**

Basically, if you still do use it that way - make sure your POCO objects are `short-lived' as well - but that gets painful I'm sure.